# UWP Map Control Missing Detail Roads Details

Tags: bing-maps, uwp-maps

Hello for some reason the uwp map control doesnt appear to be working properly. To rule out any issues with my code I began testing with [UWP Sample Ui projects mapcontrol](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) When I set latitude and longitude to a geopoint other than the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0tiH.png)Seattle/Washington state area the roads, accessways, and labels dont show in the new area. I could replicate the problem if I pan far away from Washignton the control would not update the roads and the roads or details either. It looks like the washington state maps are downloaded offline but I have a great internet connection 20-40Mb.

--Scenario1.xaml.cs
  private async void MyMap_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myMap.Center = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 33.448376, Longitude = -112.074036 });

```
        myMap.ZoomLevel = 20;
        SetMapStyle();
        SetMapProjection();
        await myMap.TrySetViewAsync(MainPage.SeattleGeopoint, 12);
    }
```

Has anyone else encountered these issues? I am or my users required to download all of the state maps for it to run?

These's other promising solutions xaml-mapcontrol and using a webview to reference maps but its just a same the built in uwp control doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The built-in MapControl *should* work. If you have Washington maps downloaded offline, and you only run into the problem when panning away from Washington or setting the center to be someplace else in the world, there must be a problem with downloading the map data. The screenshot you posted with the blurry roads and no labels supports this.

To verify, try loading Chicago to confirm it is blurry, and then download the offline maps for Illinois to see if it resolves the problem. You should *not* have to do this, but it could help to verify the issue.

I would try "Deleting all maps" from the Offline Maps section of Settings, to see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply; it was very insightful. I downloaded the map for the state of Illinois  and the roads show . I also tried deploying my app to a remote device and works without having to download any offline maps.

Comment: Some users have reported issues with various networking proxy clients being installed that interfere with map data being downloaded. The offline download feature using a slightly different networking path that sometimes works when the normal path doesn't. Are you running any networking proxy software like the Juniper Pulse client, or behind a corporate proxy server?